# Yii 1 Yii::import doen'ts work but include do

Tags: php, yii, include, yii1.x

I have change my provider and i have this error now

> Fatal error: Class 'GxController' not found in
>   /home/clients/bbbf03544f22c763cd3acfefa31454be/web/protected/controllers/SiteController.php
>   on line 6

i used to import like this :

```
Yii::import(‘application.components.GxController);
```

and now i have to do

```
include Yii::app()->getBasePath().'/components/GxController.php';
```

any idea ? i doesn't want to change all the code..

before i use php 5.4 and now 5.6

Many thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix it with a .htaccess files like :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: How rewrite rules could affect imports?

Comment: i don't know does it impact the path ? my old .htaccess was full of old stuff i don't need now..